# Firebase Android ChildEventListener fires when denied by rules (RTDB)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a game where both clients have the ability to determine "game over" state by writing to a "gameover" node:

```
- gameId
- - gameUpdates
- - gameover
```

I am attaching a ChildEventListener to "gameId", and when a snapshot comes I determine the key of the snapshot and act accordingly.

As the game can end in various ways, I want only the first write to "gameover" to count, to make sure the game ends the same way for both players. Hence in RTDB rules I have set `!data.exists()` for "gameover".

To my problem:
If my write to "gameover" gets denied by the rules (the other player already wrote something to this node), then I still get a local snapshot with the data I wrote, even if it was never written to the database.

Now, [I am aware of this answer by @puf](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2461), where if you write something with a ServerValue.TIMESTAMP you get one local and one actual snapshot. And that is expected behaviour, but I am not writing any timestamp here.

What I want to know: Is this behaviour the same as with timestamp writes? And is there a way to ignore local snapshots? Also open to alternative ideas to make this work :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I wrote an explanation below, but it may depend on the actual code: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application writes to the database, the local SDK always immediately fires the events for that write - even before sending it to the server. There is no way to suppress these events.

---

If the write subsequently gets rejected by the server, the SDK will fire so-called reconciliatory events to allow you to update the local state of your app.

So for example, if you added a child, the initial event will be `onChildAdded`. If the server rejects this write, the SDK will fire `onChildRemoved` to allow you to fix the local state.